# Outlook Add-in, RibbonType Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer and Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have an Outlook 2010 Add-in coded in .NET 4.0/VS.NET 2010, C#. The Add-in extends the Ribbon => it adds a `RibbonTab` with 4 RibbonButtons to (`RibbonType` Property is set to) `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` and `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read`.

Now, if the user clicks on one of the RibbonButtons, how can i determine if the user clicked on the button which is added to the `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` OR `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to create (2) Ribbons with a shared capability library. When you call your shared library - you can pass the context of which ribbon action was clicked.

The better choice though is to check the [`ActiveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865654%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property of the application to determine which context the user is in via [`ThisAddin.Application.ActiveWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865654%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```cs
 var windowType = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveWindow();
 if (windowType is Outlook.Explorer)
 {
     Outlook.Explorer exp = type as Outlook.Explorer;
     // you have an explorer context
 }
 else if (windowType is Outlook.Inspector)
 {
     Outlook.Inspector exp = type as Outlook.Inspector;
     // you have an inspector context
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

The proposal from SilverNinja pointed me in a direction .. finally my code is:

```
                // get active Window
            object activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();
            if (activeWindow is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer)
            {
                // its an explorer window
                Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
                Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
                for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (selection[i + 1] is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selection[i + 1] as Outlook.MailItem;
                        CreateFormOrForm(mailItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Logging.Logging.Log.Debug("One or more of the selected items are not of type mail message..!");
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("One or more of the selected items are not of type mail message..");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (activeWindow is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector)
            {
                // its an inspector window
                Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                CreateFormOrForm(mailItem);
            }
```

maybe this is of help for someone else ...