# Outlook Ribbon XML - Get Active MailItem when other email item is open

Tags: outlook, vsto, ribbon

What's the best way to retrieve the current active mailitem for all situations. So new mail, current mail, inline reply and normal reply. 
My current code works ok until user has an email open in different screen. This is considered to be the active item.

```
MailItem mailItem = null;

      Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
      if(inspector != null)
      {

        object item = inspector.CurrentItem;
        if(item is MailItem)
        {
          mailItem = item as MailItem;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inspector);
        inspector = null;
      }
      else
      {
        Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        try
        {
          mailItem = explorer.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveInlineResponse", BindingFlags.GetProperty
                                                                             | BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                             BindingFlags.Public, null, explorer, null)
            as MailItem;
        }
        catch(Exception) { }

        if(mailItem == null)
        {
          if(explorer.Selection.Count > 0)
          {
            mailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
          }
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(explorer);
        explorer = null;
      }
      return mailItem;
```

Solution : Use the IRibbonControl

```
internal static MailItem GetMailItem(IRibbonControl control)
    {
      // Check to see if an item is selected in explorer or we are in inspector.
      if(control.Context is Inspector)
      {
        Inspector inspector = (Inspector)control.Context;

        if(inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem)
        {
          return inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
        }
      }

      if(control.Context is Explorer)
      {
        Explorer explorer = (Explorer)control.Context;

        Selection selectedItems = explorer.Selection;
        if(selectedItems.Count != 1)
        {
          return null;
        }

        if(selectedItems[1] is MailItem)
        {
          return selectedItems[1] as MailItem;
        }
      }

      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Application.ActiveWindow` property. You can then check if it is an `Explorer` or an `Inspector` and act accordingly.

If this is called from a ribbon button context, you really need to use `RibbonControl.Context` (`RibbonControl` is passed as a parameter to your event handler).

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for your reply. I fixed it with your suggestion. Thanks so much

Comment: Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16143560/1129978) of the sample code.