# c# VSTO problem with correct syntax with - activeWindow is Explorer

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

My VSTO Outlook addon, sending emails when user click `Send` button. Outlook has two options how send email, from `explorer` (Write code to handle message if sourced from explorer) or from `Inspector` (openened "double-clicked" message)

best source is https://stackoverflow.com/a/16143560/3681759

and best answers @Dmitry Streblechenko

im sure im getting close, but now im faccing problem how get values `.TO` and `Subject` when email is created in explorer

`part of code :`

```
object activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();

if (activeWindow is Explorer)
{
    Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    MailItem mailExplorer = explorer as MailItem; 

    String Subject = mailExplorer.Subject;
    String FromEmailAddress = mailExplorer.SenderEmailAddress;
    String ToEmailAddress = mailExplorer.Recipients[1].AddressEntry.Address;
    String EmailHTMLBody = mailExplorer.HTMLBody;
    String EmailBody = mailExplorer.Body;
```

My error show up on line: i thing error means, `String Subject` is ````null```

```
 String Subject = mailExplorer.Subject;
```

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting `Explorer` object to `MailItem`. You cannot do that.

Use `Explorer.Selection` collection (if `Count > 0`) to access selected items. If you want the inline response message being composed, use `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse` property. Check to make sure it is not null.